# Stringifying a QuerySet

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

Will the queryset be evaluated i.e will django make database hits if i just stringify the queryset ?

i.e Will the below statement make database hits?

`str(Model.objects.all())`

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated)  doesn't cleary mentions about `str()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short answer

Yes, because in this case `str` uses `__repr__`.

#### Reasoning:

According to [this excellent SO answer on **repr** vs **str**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2626364/2715819) in python:

> if `__repr__` is defined, and `__str__` is not, the object will behave
>   as though `__str__=__repr__`

Looking at [the django code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/db/models/query/#QuerySet) we see that `__repr__` is defined and `__str__` is not, so we can reason that the docs on `repr` cover `str` as well.

#### Try it

It's pretty easy to test this sort of thing out yourself:

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> len(connection.queries)
0
>>> str(User.objects.all())
"<QuerySet [<User: test>, ...]>"
>>> len(connection.queries)
1
```

#### Comment on some other answers

Database is not directly hit by calling `all()`, which is the beauty of the lazy queryset evaluation.  A DB query is not triggered until the elements of the response are required (as stated in the documentation pointed to by the OP).

Answer (score 0):

For stringfy, i think there won't be any Database hit. only for `Model.objects.all()` it will hit the database. Once the result came, It will stringfy the queryset without database hit.

**str()** is just type conversion functions to strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will only hit the DB once. Calling `Model.objects.all()` will include an SQL conversion that gets sent to the DB. Once received by your application, the `str()` call only calls the `__str__` method inside a Model. If not defined, I think it will return a default syntax involving the primary key(which I can't remember off the top of my head since I always define `__str__` for readability and testing purposes).